# Getting week number from date using Arcade with ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, date, arcade

How can I get the week number (week position in year) from a date with ArcGIS Online’s Arcade?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/date_functions/ ?

Comment: Yeah, can't find anything about week numbers...

Comment: Have a look again and search for `Weekday(dateValue) `.

Comment: @TomazicM I am searching for weeknumber of the year. This is giving me the day number of the week ;)

Comment: Ups, sorry, didn't look carefully. In this case you'll have to calculate number of days from the beginning of the year and divide them by 7.

Comment: No, because week 1 did no have 7 days....

Comment: So, thats not accurate

Comment: There are multiple ways of counting week numbers.  ISO 8601 has the first week of year as the week with the first Thursday. US tends to base it on the week with the first Sunday. And there are several other ones too - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering.  
Which one are you looking for?